Want the R.string.value without invoking composable function
I have a simple enum class in which I try to override the toString method. However I would like to connect it to R.string values and there is where my problem starts.
All methods I tried to use, work with @Composable functions. I tried find some ways without over context but those were also all composable. I have no clue.
If I add composable connotation I get the error:

@Composable annotation mismatch with overridden function: @Composable public open fun toString(): String defined in com.blblbla. Season, public open fun toString(): String defined in kotlin.Enum

enum class Season{
    Spring,
    Summer,
    Autumn,
    Winter;

    @Composable
    override fun toString(): String {
        return when (this) {
            Spring -> stringResource(R.string.Spring)
            Summer -> stringResource(R.string.Summer)
            Autumn -> stringResource(R.string.Autumn)
            Winter -> stringResource(R.string.Winter)
        }
    }
}

I tried to import Context, but this did not work since I can't get a Context assigned.
context: Context = LocalContext.current <- composable function again.
context.resources.getString(R.string.Spring)
I just run in circles with asking the ais. I don't know why it shall be so hard to get a function to link to strings.xml.android without invoking any composables.

Your problem is not tied to composables. You cannot refer to the value of string resources without a Context. The stringResource() top-level function simply leverages being inside a composition to be able to access LocalContext.current. IMHO, architecturally, what you are doing is incorrect. Having your enum know the ID of the string resource is fine (e.g., via a val property). However, it is not an enum's job to handle business logic such as "find the right text representation" -- that is the job of a UI layer, perhaps in the form of a ViewModel.
